Is It Fair to Be Tested in This Way
I’ve been experiencing waswas for a couple of months now, and it’s making me question something. If Allah is the most just, how is it fair that we are created and then placed in a test we may not want to be a part of, and if we fail, we face eternal punishment in hell? Is it just to be tested in this way

sure it is fair. Justice is to put anything where it belongs to, Allah knows what and how you are better than you know yourself, and He manages our lives accordingly: ‍‍... perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not [2:216]
